# What kind of filter is this?

Tags: control-systems, digital-filters

Is this filter a BPF?
$$\dfrac{z}{z-a}$$

where $a$ is some complex number?

If we put a pole somewhere on the unit circle it will emphasise a certain frequency, is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you put a pole *approaching* the unit circle (but not on the unit circle, as this will create an unstable filter) , you will have a bandpass. The center frequency of this bandpass filter depends on how many radians along the unit circle where you have placed the pole (the pole's 'degree').

Moving counter-clockwise from zero will give you an increasing center frequency of the bandpass filter.

Once you start moving towards zero on the Z-plane and away from the unit circle, you will decrease the sharpness Q and consequently increase the bandwidth.

Comment: If you have a pole *on* the unit circle you have infinite Q and an unstable filter. So it's not really useful as a bandpass filter.

Comment: Good point, will edit

Comment: also, keep in mind that with purely real coefficients you can't do a 1st-order BPF.  so you really need two of these with complex conjugate `a` to do this for real.  and then it will be 2nd-order.